# Frequency of a Photon and Waves

Tags: photons

Waves are oscillating so the term frequency is associated with them, but what is meant by the frequency of a photon as an equation says $E=hf$? Does this mean that photon also oscillate in a particular direction?

Answer (score -1):

A photon is defined as the perturbation of the U(1) gauge field. Since it seems you just want a simple thing to sort your doubt, I'll provide a non-technical 'intuitive' answer.

Think of a photon as simply being a 'quanta' bundle of localized energy in the Maxwell's gauge field. This is done mathematically by constructing wave-packets out of the photon propagator. At this point, frequency is simply a label for the photon. It tells us what wavelength, or energy, or momentum, does this particular photon correspond to. This frequency does not imply that the photon is oscillating. A photon is just a name for a collection of localized wave-packets.

In fact in QFT, we don't speak of a photon of frequency this or that. It is just an excitation of massless field carrying spin-1 modes. The field itself will have frequencies and so on.

I hope I did not confuse you further.

Comment: hope springs eternal ;-)

Comment: My pedantic pet peeve: "quanta" is the plural of "quantum". You can't have "a quanta". (Also, alumni is the plural of alumnus)

Comment: Haha @ThePhoton

Comment: I'd be interested in understanding what makes my response receive a down-vote? Not as a complain but looking for some constructive criticism.